# Weather data manipulation in R

Tags: r, csv, rstudio, weather

I am currently doing my research project from the university and I need to plot the precipitation of a region. I already downloaded the dataset but I don't know how I can convert it to a time series format in R. The cvs is composed by 33 columns, the first column is year, the second column is month and the next column are days from day 1 to day 31. I am wondering how I can transform this format in a time series format. For example, I want to create a column with the days in vertical and not horizontal.

I attach a picture of my csv. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hello Paola, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question. You'll receive higher quality help faster if you include a reproducible example in your question.

Comment: Your first step is convert from the current format into a "long" format.  From the tidyr package: `tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols=starts_with("Day."), names_to="Day", values_to="value", names_pattern = ".*\\.(.*)")`. From there you can concatenate the year, month and day column and convert to a Date object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses `tidyr` to convert the data into a time series. First, we generate some random data in a matrix containing 12 rows and 31 columns.

```
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(12*31,10,4),nrow = 12))
colnames(data) <- paste0("Day",1:31)
```

Next, we add `year` and `month` columns to the day columns. Note that later we'll need to clean up the months that don't have 31 days.

```
year <- rep(2019,12)
month <- 1:12

df <- cbind(year,month,data)
```

At this point, the first few rows and columns of the data looks like this:

```
> head(data[1:7])
        Day1     Day2      Day3      Day4      Day5      Day6      Day7
1  0.2484915 10.25880  8.013013 11.057882 15.396539 14.861255 13.397043
2  8.8733834 11.42535 15.123711  6.586021  1.389619  5.884448 14.292295
3 12.5584852 10.80626 12.310648  8.705159 14.809994  6.334296  5.683926
4  7.3488391  5.62349 13.917364  6.397150  7.304381  5.154961  8.024700
5  2.1801690 11.03743 14.947513  5.594491 10.229679 12.254684 12.936003
6 13.8082670 10.82822 17.330590 13.948173  3.091670  8.376202 12.647662
```

Finally, we use `tidyr` and `lubridate` to convert the columns into rows, using the numbers from the column names for the `day` variable.

```
df %>% group_by(year,month) %>%
     pivot_longer(.,starts_with("Day"),names_to = "day",names_prefix = "Day",
                  values_to = "value") %>%
     mutate(day = as.numeric(day)) %>%
     filter(((month %in% c(9,4,6,11) & day < 31) | (month == 2 & day <= 28) | 
                  month %in% c(1,3,5,7,8,10,12))) %>%
     mutate(date = ymd(sprintf("%4d-%02d-%02d",year,month,day)))-> narrowData
head(narrowData)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(narrowData)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   year, month [1]
   year month   day  value date      
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <date>    
1  2019     1     1  0.248 2019-01-01
2  2019     1     2 10.3   2019-01-02
3  2019     1     3  8.01  2019-01-03
4  2019     1     4 11.1   2019-01-04
5  2019     1     5 15.4   2019-01-05
6  2019     1     6 14.9   2019-01-06
>
```

As a final check, we'll confirm that the output data frame has 365 rows, one for each day of 2019.

```
> # count number of rows in data frame, should be 365
> nrow(narrowData)
[1] 365
>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Len! It is very helpful I got the principle of the code but I am not able to run it. I get this error: 
Error in group_by(., year, month) : 
 could not find function "group_by"

Comment: Why is this happening? and how can I solve it? I would like to learn how to solve it. Thank you in advance

Comment: I fixed it! Thanks, I just needed to add     df   <--  so like this:                                                              df <-  df %>% group_by(year,month) %>%

Comment: @PaolaGuzman - glad to see that you were able to apply the answer in your context. `dplyr` uses the pipe operator `%>%` to chain functions together.  The first `df` in the chain simply "prints" the data to use it as input to the next function in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can melt the data frame and then reorder it.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

tsdf <-  melt(df, id = 1:2, measure. = colnames(df[-c(1,2)]))

tsdf$variable <- as.numeric(str_remove(tsdf$variable, "Day."))

tsdf$Date <- as.Date(paste(tsdf$Year, tsdf$Month, tsdf$variable, sep="-"))
tsdf <- tsdf[c(5,4)]
tsdf <- tsdf[order(tsdf$Date),]
```